# How can I fix "Fatal error: class Mail not found"?

Tags: civimail

I just migrated CiviCRM back to a development environment and I am getting:

> PHP Fatal error:  Class 'Mail' not found in ../web/sites/all/modules/civicrm/CRM/Core/Config.php on line 628

This is when I am running a test mailing. The rest of the site seems OK.

CiviCRM 4.6.3 and Drupal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The development system must not have Mail. I went to

```
mysite://civicrm/admin/setting/smtp?reset=1
```

And picked 'save to database' as the mailer option as I don't really want to send mail anyway, just debug it.